# array values into square brackets [ ]

Tags: php, arrays

How I can convert array into square brackets in PHP?
Why I need this? Because in my JS code wants square brackets and inside is data

Example
["date1", "date2", "date3"]

My JS code:

```
xaxis: {
  show: false,
  type: 'datetime',
  categories: <?= $date ?>,
  ...
```

My var_dump($date):

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(19) "2020-05-04 00:00:00" [1]=> string(19) "2020-05-05 00:00:00" [2]=> string(19) "2020-05-03 00:00:00" [3]=> string(19) "2020-05-06 00:00:00" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_encode($date)` - is something what you need here